# Firebase_database plugin for flutter is not working (resolve android.arch.core:common:1.1.1.)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, build.gradle

I am new to flutter development. I want to use the firebase database. I was able to connect to firebase using the firebase analytics plugin but I was not successful in using the firebase database.

I tried to add the plugin on a time to knew where did the issue come from and know I am sure it is the firebase_database plugin.

I have successfully added the following package:

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
```

but when I add

```
firebase_database: ^3.1.0
```

I get the below error
**Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**

This error appears when I run the default flutter application (The counter app) on my Android mobile.
So I open the Android module in Android Studio to get more details about the error.
I got the following error

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':firebase_database@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: firebase_database


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':firebase_database@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: firebase_database


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':firebase_database@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: firebase_database


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':firebase_database@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:common:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: firebase_database


ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.6
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: firebase_database


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':firebase_database@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.core:common:{strictly 1.0.0}.
Show Details
Affected Modules: firebase_database


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':firebase_database@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.core:common:1.1.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: firebase_database


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':firebase_database@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: firebase_database
```

This is my pubspec.yaml file

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  firebase_database: ^3.1.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

Also, below is my project level my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Below is my app level build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.labstabs.riskometer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'` and `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'` in your project build.gradle. Let us know if it throws the same error too after changing those versions

Comment: It did throw the following error : Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1. To get more details I have to open the Android mobule in Android studio. I found that it throw the exact same error above.

Answer (score 0):

replace with this

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```